Kernel panic - not syncing error | Contabo VM
I have a Contabo server running Ubuntu v22 currently hosting some docker containers that are vital.
Contabo is using Proxmox to serve up the VPS.
I woke up this morning to my server down and upon not being able to SSH in even after some reboots I logged in via VNC only to find a Kernel panic.
I've been reading posts all day on this issue and almost all of them seem to be from updates and changes user induced, however, in this case I didn't do anything! Last time I did any updates was a couple weeks ago and it's been running fine all this time. I'm not versed enough in this situation to understand the information showing in the terminal so I'm hoping someone out there can point me in the right direction.
Right now I'm guessing something changed in the hardware maybe or something happened to the kernel but I have zero idea really. I appreciate any and all help! Also, sorry for the image only, I can't seem to copy from the VNC window.


Let's look at the output's element:
[    1.12345] tells us how many seconds after starting of Linux boot this happened.
So, we know that your system got rebooted 1.3 seconds before what you see happened.
 ---[ end Kernel panic – not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs …
Aligns with that. Your kernel can't find the device that should become its / directory.
So, either your kernel configuration in your boot loader (which might very well be the virtualizer used for your VM) is broken and points to the wrong device .
Or, the unexpected reboot is part of this, and something stopped the VM abruptly, maybe coincidentally ruining the root file system by "pulling the plug" just in a crucial moment. That's unlikely, as modern file systems are actually very hard to break this way. Losing unwritten content of files does happen, yes, but becoming impossible to mount: that would require more than just power off during usage.
Zeroth step: Locate backups. You say "vital", so I know you know that things are important, so I'm pretty optimistic you've got backups!
First step: find out why the VM was rebooted. This might very well be a question for your hoster.
Then: figure out whether the configuration of the virtualizer has changed. Download the disk image of your VM, set it up as loop back device on your computer, and verify volumes/partitions can be found. Verify the root file system is there. Check file system integrity (fsck, mounting…). Check that kernel options (especially the root= setting) is reflected in your system layout.
The rest really depends on how your virtualizer boots your operating system – it might directly load the kernel, or it might hand of to a bootloader (e.g. Grub) to do that. Figure that out! This will need someone with insight into how your virtualization system is set up.

Thank you @Marcus! That really does help my understanding of it all.
I was in communication with the support team at Contabo and they eventually took a look into my system. They're saying that I got compromised with perfcc/perfctl which is a crypto-miner malware which exploits Polkit vulnerability (CVE-2021-4034). They removed the bad file at /lib/libgcwrap.so but apparently the new kernel install failed. I will now be reinstalling the server and applying backups. Frustrating! But lessons learned.. lol
